# Xcode 9.3 Swift Crash While Initializing an NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am either losing my mind(highly likely), or there is a strange bug in Xcode 9.3. I have the following function in my app to make sure that a new entry into a Core Data model is unique to the data.

My code is as follows:

```
func parachuteUnique(parachute: ParachuteData) -> Bool {

    var predicate = NSCompoundPredicate() //the final compound predicate is set in an If Else statement, so the variable needs to be initialized first.

    let material = parachute.material.rawValue //returns a string
    let shape = parachute.shape.rawValue //returns a string
    let area = parachute.area.value //area is a Measurement and returns a double

    let shapePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "shape == %@", shape)
    let areaPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "area == %@", area)
    let materialPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "material == %@", material)
...
}
```

This code crashes on the areaPredicate initialization with an error stating:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3fb2ae297396d091)
```

The value of area at the time of the crash is 0.072969999999999993.

This crash only occurs on a real iPhone 7 Plus, but not on the simulator. This is called as part of a function that seeds data into Core Data model. The crash occurs before and after updating the phone to 11.3.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's astonishing that your code does not crash on the simulator. `%@` in `NSPredicate` format is clearly defined as to take [_an object value_](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW2). You can use `NSPredicate(format: "area == %f", area)` or  `NSPredicate(format: "area == %lf", area)` when `area` is `Double`, but generally comparing `Double` with `==` may not work in many cases. You should better check your `areaPredicate` was really working as expected in non-crash cases.

Comment: I will try that. I have been trying to see if there was another predicate format to use. On the simulator, it has been performing as expected.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the current build and then installing that once again after the update as migh be core data faces issue in it

Comment: OOPer, that is the solution. If you make it an answer, I will accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, if anyone knows of a good discussion on predicate formatting syntax, please let me know. A Google search on %f comes up blank. I can find some pages where it is used in code, but nothing discussing exactly what it means. Thanks.